# Mark post for later?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Is it possible to mark a post in some way? I sometimes find nice questions and I want to work on them later when I have time, but often later is difficult to find the same question. Am I missing something or there is a way?

Thanks in advance,
Umberto

Comment: Clicking the star beneath the question score will mark the question as a [favourite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/214632), and will then appear in the "Favorites" tab in your user profile.

Comment: You can maintain a file on your computer/draft email on your email provider/write the question number on a piece of paper.

Comment: @Asafkaragila thanks. I tought about that ;-) I was thinking about something in MSE self...

Comment: @ArthurFischer thanks. Will do this.

Answer (score 4):

(An answer was provided in comments, so this answer is to get the question off the unanswered list)

You can add the question to your [favorites list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), which is then saved under the "favorites" tab in your profile. To add a question to your favorites list, just click the star below the voting arrows on the question.

Do note that a user's favorites list is publicly visible.